# How to refresh a FutureBuilder in stateless widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using provider as a state management solution and I want a way to refresh the FutureBuilder without setState

Comment: use getx plugin https://pub.dev/packages/get , you can refresh in stateless widget

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you using provider use StreamProvider instead of FutureBuilder

```
StreamProvider<List<AuthInfo>>.value(
  value: myDatabase.authInfosDao.watch(),
  initialData: [],
  child: Consumer<List<AuthInfo>>(builder: (context, data, _) {

},);
```

Comment: The FutureBuilder is working pretty fine with me except when I want to refresh it, I'll have to leave the screen and enter it again to make it refresh would StreamProvider help my in my case?